# Linking to an animated gif, and shrinking the display size

Tags: feature-request, images

I am trying to embed the following animation in a question, and it works fine, even after being automatically copied to *imgur.com:

[image]

... but it's too big for my taste, so I'll shrink it by applying a small "m" at the end:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/n31t7**m**.gif

[image]

The problem is that the animation stops working.  It would be nice if that didn't happen, and the animation still worked.

If you do get this to work, I would be very interested in seeing the source code for it.

Comment: The "m" is for "motionless", obviously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are allowed to use HTML to produce images in your posts, which also lets you specify the width and/or height, like so:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n31t7.gif" width="320" />
```

**Produces:**

[image]